# Is there an easier way to add common namespaces to XAML?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I was curious if there is an easier way to add or manage namespaces in XAML. I add some of the same namespaces to almost every window and control that I create, and I have gotten in the habit of copying and pasting a block of text after their creation. For example, I will typically add the following to every window:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

Can the default namespaces for a new window be changed? Or is there a good extension to manage namespaces? With no more macros in VS2012, is there a way of using some other form of hotkey or shortcut to accomplish this goal?

Comment: While I'm not sure about specifying default namespaces, you would probably find this helpful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and

Comment: Really good question about overriding Window's initial code

Answer (score 0):

You could customize the according VS templates to fit your need.

I don't have the location for VS2012 ready (only got 2012 Express on this machine) but you shouldn't have much trouble finding them for your VS version.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a good extension to manage namespaces?

Resharper will do the trick.